# log4j not logging to file

Tags: java, log4j

I've got a simple Tomcat web service that I'd like to see the logs for. I figured log4j would be the easiest solution. So far it will log to the in my dev environment, but it won't log to a file.

Here is my log4j.properties file (located in the src/ folder):

```
#Add these properties to all CallRouter-->data-->ddlog4j.properties files at the bottom to configure the Transactions.jar logging for DB and WS messaging.
log4j.rootCategory=ALL, MAIN_LOG
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console

#Defines the <logging level>, <appender> for custom logging.
log4j.category.com.ddvc.android.resource=INFO, SupportWebServices

#### Transactions.jar appender INFO setup
log4j.logger.com.ddvc.android.resource=INFO
log4j.appender.ResourceInfo=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ResourceInfo.File=C:/test/SupportWebServices.log
log4j.appender.ResourceInfo.Append=true
log4j.appender.ResourceInfo.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm
log4j.appender.ResourceInfo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ResourceInfo.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS]} %p %c{1} (%M: %L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.ResourceInfo.Threshold=INFO

# Output to Console
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]} %p %c{1} (%M: %L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=CONSOLE
```

And in my java files I have (located in src/com/ddvc/android/resource):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Path("/pulse")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class PulseResource {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PulseResource.class.getName());

    @GET
    @Path("list")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public List<Pulse> postXML() {
        LOGGER.info("Start: list");
    }
}
```

Like I said I can see the logs to the Console:

```
INFO  [2015-02-19 15:19:34,961] [http-bio-8080-exec-3] [PulseResource] [] - Start: list
```

But I don't see any file created or logged to in the C:\test folder. (plan to change it to ${catalina.base}\logs\SupportWebServices.log)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console`

to

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,ResourceInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line:

```
log4j.rootCategory=ALL, MAIN_LOG
```

edit this line:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,ResourceInfo
```

Comment: Thank you! I took out the "rootCategory" and added in the "ResourceInfo" to the root logger and that worked.

I also changed the CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO, and changed the: 
    log4j.rootLogger=,INFO,CONSOLE,ResourceInfo